# what is the default value of enum variable?

Tags: c++, c, enums

I have a question about enum variable in c++:

```
type enmu {
   DAY1 = 1,
   DAY2,
   DAY3,
   DAY4
} DAYS;

void main() {
   DAYS days;
}
```

then what is the default value of days?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's uninitialized and *undefined behavior* to read the value.

Just like saying

```
int x;
```

`x` doesn't have a value until you initialize it.

Comment: ok, then if I do this: if(days) {//do something},what will happen?

Comment: @ratzip anything can happen. It's undefined behavior if `days` wasn't initialized.

Comment: what you mean by undefined behavior? can you give a example?

Comment: @ratzip what's confusing? You wanted examples of what undefined behavior is, right?

Comment: in my case, what default value will be?

Comment: @ratzip there is none. The `if` would be illegal.

Comment: thank you man, I read my code again, and figure it out now,thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

> then what is the default value of days?`

Like for any automatic object, the value of the `days` object is indeterrminate.

Now if you declared your object with the `static` specifier:

```
static DAYS days;
```

Then like for any static object of an arithmetic type, the initial value would be `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerations behave pretty much like integers, i.e. they don't have a well-defined default value. You cannot read the variable's value before initializing it without invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, adding to the words, said before: you really *do* may have default value for a *static* enum variable. But be carefull -- it will be 0 (as well as all other static variables). Consider following code:

```
#include <iostream>

enum _t_test {
                test_1 = 1,
                test_2 = 2,
                test_3 = 3,
             };

static enum _t_test t;

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Value of t is: " << t;
    return 0;
```

}

It will print 0, but your enums are in range from 1..3. So be aware of it.